# How do i find empty space in array and fill it with part of code / how do i rand 3 randed arrays into one and shuffle it randomly?

Tags: c++

> Got a task to do password generator.

> Right now i have a problem with the output because if i build the code

> [here is the outcome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTreZ.png)

> so my problem is that i need to get something more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uisGr.png) with my own input choice and to mix it into each other so it wouldn't go like the first picture.

> i hopefully made myself more clear about my problem.

> i - stands for the number for cycle.

> la - stands for the lower alphabet for cycle.

> ha - stands for the higher alphabet for cycle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
const char num[] = "0123456789";
const char lower_alp[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const char higher_alp[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int sizeofnum = sizeof(num) - 1;
int sizeoflower_alp = sizeof(lower_alp) - 1;
int sizeofhigher_alp = sizeof(higher_alp) - 1;

int main()
{
   int password_length = 0, nums, loweralp, higheralp;
   cout << "Enter password length: ";
   cin >> password_length;
   cout << "How many lower alphabet symbols do you want in the password:";
   cin >> loweralp;
   cout << "How many higher alphabet symbols do you want in the password:";
   cin >> higheralp;
   cout << "How many numbers do you want in the password:";
   cin >> nums;
   srand(time(NULL));
       for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
        cout << num[rand() % sizeofnum];
    }
    for (char la = 0; la < loweralp; la++) {
        cout << lower_alp[rand() % sizeoflower_alp];
    }
    for (char ha = 0; ha < higheralp; ha++) {
        cout << higher_alp[rand() % sizeofhigher_alp];
    }
     
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not simply `alphabet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` then pick elements from it randomly? Not sure if I understand the issue

Comment: please do not use pictures for text. Please include text as text in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you want to combine a random selection of characters from each of the 3 sets in a random order, then a convenient way to ensure you end up with a randomized selection from each set combined in a random order would be to:

- shuffle each set initially,
- create a string concatenating the needed number of characters from each shuffled string, and
- shuffle the concatenated string.

You can build in that direction based upon the `shuffle_string()` answer received to do:

```cpp
void shuffle_from_sets(std::string& str, size_t n1, size_t n2, size_t n3)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    
    std::string s1 {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"},
                s2 {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"},
                s3 {"0123456789"};
    
    std::shuffle (s1.begin(), s1.end(), g);     /* shuffle sets */
    std::shuffle (s2.begin(), s2.end(), g);
    std::shuffle (s3.begin(), s3.end(), g);
    
    /* create string from shuffled sets */
    str = s1.substr (0, n1) + s2.substr (0, n2) + s3.substr (0, n3);
        
    std::shuffle(str.begin(), str.end(), g);    /* shuffle final string */
}
```

(**note:** you would want to **validate** that `n1`, `n2`, `n3` are less than or equal to the length of the set each draws from -- that if left to you)

You can also add a set with special characters to strengthen your final password, e.g. `std::string s4 {"~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\\:\";'<>?,./"};`

A complete example would be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

void shuffle_from_sets(std::string& str, size_t n1, size_t n2, size_t n3)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    
    std::string s1 {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"},
                s2 {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"},
                s3 {"0123456789"};
    
    std::shuffle (s1.begin(), s1.end(), g);     /* shuffle sets */
    std::shuffle (s2.begin(), s2.end(), g);
    std::shuffle (s3.begin(), s3.end(), g);
    
    /* create string from shuffled sets */
    str = s1.substr (0, n1) + s2.substr (0, n2) + s3.substr (0, n3);
        
    std::shuffle(str.begin(), str.end(), g);    /* shuffle final string */
}

int main (void) {
    
    std::string s{};
    size_t n1, n2, n3;
    
    std::cout << "no chars [a-z]  : ";
    if (!(std::cin >> n1)) {
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "no chars [A-Z]  : ";
    if (!(std::cin >> n2)) {
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "no chars [0-9]  : ";
    if (!(std::cin >> n3)) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    shuffle_from_sets (s, n1, n2, n3);
    
    std::cout << "shuffled string : " << s << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Building your randomized passwords from the sets would look similar to:

```
$ ./bin/string_shuffle_sets
no chars [a-z]  : 6
no chars [A-Z]  : 4
no chars [0-9]  : 3
shuffled string : LtW9bu53ksxIC
```

or

```
$ ./bin/string_shuffle_sets
no chars [a-z]  : 6
no chars [A-Z]  : 4
no chars [0-9]  : 3
shuffled string : yJKqP5hnbi3Q6
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

using a `std::string` to store the characters You can randomly sort it using a function `string_shuffle` that will do the job.

```
void string_shuffle(std::string& str)
{
    auto rd = std::random_device{};
    auto rng = std::default_random_engine{ rd() };
    std::shuffle(str.begin(), str.end(), rng);
}
```

**Tested using c++17**

Comment: My answer got a bit over-engineered for the task, I like yours better

Answer (score 0):

[Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

You can, however, in a CPP file (not H file) or inside a function put individual `using std::string;` etc.  (See [SF.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file).)

---

use `constexpr` for constants that are known at compile time.

---

None of these are necessary:

```
int sizeofnum = sizeof(num) - 1;
int sizeoflower_alp = sizeof(lower_alp) - 1;
int sizeofhigher_alp = sizeof(higher_alp) - 1;
```

and if you did need them, use `size_t`, make them `constexpr`, and generally don't use `sizeof` to determine collection sizes.

---

### Don't repeat yourself.

You have three different lists, and duplicate the exact code for picking characters from them.  Make it a general function that takes parameters.

This is the first step:  choose `n` random characters from a list.  The function can be declared like this:
`string choose_n_rand (string_view choices, size_t n)`
and the implementation should use [uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), **not** the nasty legacy `rand` function.

---

Call the three parts, and combine them into one string.  The code would look something like this:

```
string pw = choose_n_rand (num, nums);
pw += choose_n_rand (lower_alpha, lower_alphas);
pw += choose_n_rand (upper_alpha, upper_alphas);
```

and then shuffle the resulting string, by calling `shuffle` from the standard library.  To do that, you need to know about the random number library as that's one of the parameters.  Look at the [examples on Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/shuffle).

You want

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
```

as global variables at the top of the file, so that `choose_n_rand` can make use of the same `gen`.

To follow on the code above, the line would be:

```
std::ranges::shuffle (pw,gen);
```

Note that the example on the linked web page uses an array; but it works with any kind of collection so here we're passing a `std::string`.

## recap

To answer your questions,

1. You don't *find empty space in an array* to make your results.  Rather, you use a container that can grow as you add things to it.
2. You can combine three separate result strings into one easily by using operations on the `std::string` class.  Above, I used `+=`.  There are many possibilities.  Point is, these operations exist as part of the container classes, and you don't need to figure it out from scratch on a primitive array!
3. To shuffle, call `shuffle`.  **know what's in the standard library**.

Answer (score -1):

You could just save the desired characters into a string and then pick from that randomly. Doing that your code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
const char num[] = "0123456789";
const char lower_alp[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const char higher_alp[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int sizeofnum = sizeof( num ) - 1;
int sizeoflower_alp = sizeof( lower_alp ) - 1;
int sizeofhigher_alp = sizeof( higher_alp ) - 1;

int main()
{
    int password_length = 0, nums, loweralp, higheralp;
    cout << "Enter password length: ";
    cin >> password_length;
    cout << "How many lower alphabet symbols do you want in the password:";
    cin >> loweralp;
    cout << "How many higher alphabet symbols do you want in the password:";
    cin >> higheralp;
    cout << "How many numbers do you want in the password:";
    cin >> nums;
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    string possibleCharacters = "";
    string password = "";
    for( int i = 0; i < nums; i++ )
    {
        possibleCharacters += num[rand() % sizeofnum];
    }
    for( char la = 0; la < loweralp; la++ )
    {
        possibleCharacters += lower_alp[rand() % sizeoflower_alp];
    }
    for( char ha = 0; ha < higheralp; ha++ )
    {
        possibleCharacters += higher_alp[rand() % sizeofhigher_alp];
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < password_length; i++ )
    {
        int nextCharacterIndex = 0;
        if( i != 0 )
        {
            nextCharacterIndex = rand() % ( possibleCharacters.length() );
        }     
        password += possibleCharacters[nextCharacterIndex];
        possibleCharacters.erase( possibleCharacters.begin() + nextCharacterIndex );
    }
    cout << password;
    return 0;
}
```